# Slow requests in browser are significantly faster with cURL

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, http, curl

Apologies for the relatively vague problem...

I am working on a Springboot + React web app, and I'm having a lot of trouble with page load times locally, particularly due to the requests that the front end makes taking very long. While load times vary, they can take anywhere from 15 seconds to an entire minute, and I'm not sure why. I've brought this up with my team a few times in the past but no one else seems to be experiencing this, and this doesn't seem to be an issue on any other environments.

I can provide a screen shot and their wait times...

[image: Offending Requests Screenshot]

Now, when I copy the requests (from largeLogo to largeLogo) as cURLs from my browser and throw them all into a shell script to run in parallel (i.e. curl ... & curl ... & .... wait) and time the script, it only takes about 8-9 seconds to complete.

Since I'm copying the cURLs straight from the browser, I would imagine that I am running the exact same set of requests... So why is it that they take at the very least twice as long when they are called from the front end? Has anyone encountered such a problem before? Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might investigate this further?

Thanks in advance from a clueless intern...

Comment: What does this have to do with oracle?

Comment: That's the database I'm using... I guess it probably isn't relevant to the problem; I'll remove the tag.

Comment: Hey sir. Did you find any solutions for this? Im experiencing same issue for a long time now :(

Comment: Unfortunately I never did... 

I did a little bit more experimenting and found that when I made these requests via a python script, they'd be fast like when I'd cURL them, whereas if I used postman, they'd be slow like in the browser. Not sure if that information is of any use, but maybe someone might have an idea as to what the issue might be...